# getimagesize returns the large value of a image resolution

Tags: php

The resolution of this image is 3000*4000. width = 3000 and Height = 4000.
url- https://ibb.co/0mKkWYD

**getimagesize** returning the height first because it is larger than width. So the resolution becomes **4000*3000**, where the actual is **3000*4000**. I need to know which is width and which is height. Is there any way?

Comment: The first index of the result of `getimagesize()` is `3000` for that image. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which shows the incorrect width/height of the image you have.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns an array with up to 7 elements. Not all image types will
> include the channels and bits elements.
>
> Index 0 and 1 contains respectively the width and the height of the
> image.

Comment: I think it's a bug of PHP. index 0 contains the larger value among height and width.  Not the width. You can test it with the image I have given.

Comment: I understand now. @CBroe's comment, if you haven't seen it already, might be just what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. @Chizaram. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.

list($width, $height) = getimagesize('IMG-20211026-170113.jpg');

echo $width;

echo $height;

this will give you width and height separately

Comment: It's not a solution. I already tested like this. It will print width= 4000 and then height= 3000. But the actual is width= 3000 and then height= 4000. test yourself what happens. I think it's a bug of php.

Comment: I have tried this and this give me the correct width and height of your attached image. try once again paste the code same and enter the correct image path than let me know if not working